# Swapchain and Render Pass created successfully, but validation layers give an error when using them

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am trying to render a triangle and I'm following a tutorial from https://vulkan-tutorial.org

I am using GLFW, GLSL and Visual Studio 2017.

When render pass is created, it's value is always `0xc`, and when swapchain is created, it's value is always `0x2`. Creation functions always return `VK_SUCCESS`, and there is no validation layer output.

When I try to create a frame buffer, using `vkCreateFramebuffer()` I get prompted that my render pass object handle is invalid, and that my ImageView object handles are invalid. Their values are always `0x6`, `0x7`, and `0x8`.

Also, when I try to invoke `vkAcquireNextImageKHR()`, I get prompted that my swapchain object handle is invalid.

My swapchain creation code is below. Please, ignore the comments, they are for learning purposes only.

```
void Swapchain::initSwapchain() {
    VkPresentModeKHR presentMode = getAvaiablePresentMode();
    QueueFamilyIndices indices = *mainWindow->getRenderer()->getQueueIndices();

    swapchainCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    swapchainCreateInfo.surface = this->mainWindow->getSurface();
    swapchainCreateInfo.minImageCount = swapchainImageCount;                                    //Bufferovanje slika display buffera, koliko slika odjednom moze biti u redu
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageFormat = this->mainWindow->getSurfaceFormat().format;
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageColorSpace = this->mainWindow->getSurfaceFormat().colorSpace;
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageExtent = this->swapExtent;
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageArrayLayers = 1;                                                   //Koliko slojeva ima slika (1 je obicno renderovanje, 2 je stetoskopsko)
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;                       //Za koju vrstu operacija koristimo slike? Renderujemo ih, sto znaci da su oni COLOR ATTACHMENTS                        
    if (indices.getGraphicsFamilyIndex() != indices.getPresentationFamilyIndex()) {
        uint32_t queueIndices[] = { indices.getGraphicsFamilyIndex(), indices.getPresentationFamilyIndex() };
        swapchainCreateInfo.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_CONCURRENT;                      //Slika moze da se koristi paralelno, bez transfera vlasnistva nad slikom.
        swapchainCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 2;
        swapchainCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = queueIndices;
    }
    else {
        swapchainCreateInfo.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;                       //Slika je u vlasnistvu jednog reda u jedno vreme, i vlasnistvo mora biti prebaceno na drugi da bi taj drugi mogao da ga koristi.
        swapchainCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;                                          //Za exclusive je uvek 0
        swapchainCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;                                      //Ignorisemo za Exclusive
    }

    swapchainCreateInfo.preTransform = mainWindow->getSurfaceCapatibilities().currentTransform; //mainWindow->getCapabilities().currentTransform ako necemo transformaciju. VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR;
    swapchainCreateInfo.compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;                     //Alfa kanal SURFACE-a, da li je ona transparentna
    swapchainCreateInfo.presentMode = presentMode;                                              //Vertical Sync
    swapchainCreateInfo.clipped = VK_TRUE;                                                      //Ukljucujemo clipping, jako bitno za telefone
    swapchainCreateInfo.oldSwapchain = VK_NULL_HANDLE;                                          //Ako rekonstruisemo swapchain, pokazivac na stari

    util->ErrorCheck(vkCreateSwapchainKHR(renderer->getDevice(), &swapchainCreateInfo, nullptr, &swapchain));
    util->ErrorCheck(vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(renderer->getDevice(), swapchain, &swapchainImageCount, nullptr));
}

void Swapchain::initSwapchainImgs()
{
    images.resize(swapchainImageCount);
    imageViews.resize(swapchainImageCount);

    util->ErrorCheck(vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(renderer->getDevice(), swapchain, &swapchainImageCount, images.data()));

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < swapchainImageCount; i++) {
        VkImageViewCreateInfo imgCreateInfo = {};
        imgCreateInfo.components.r = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_R;
        imgCreateInfo.components.g = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_G;
        imgCreateInfo.components.b = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_B;
        imgCreateInfo.components.a = VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_A;
        imgCreateInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        imgCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
        imgCreateInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
        imgCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        imgCreateInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
        imgCreateInfo.format = this->imagesFormat;
        imgCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
        imgCreateInfo.image = images[i];
        imgCreateInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;


        util->ErrorCheck(vkCreateImageView(renderer->getDevice(), &imgCreateInfo, nullptr, &imageViews[i]));
    }
}
```

Render pass creation code:

```
void RenderPass::createColor() {
    VkAttachmentDescription attachment = {};
    VkAttachmentReference reference = {};
    VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
    VkRenderPassCreateInfo info = {};

    attachment.format = surfaceFormat.format;                   //Mora da se poklapa sa formatom slika iz swapchaina
    attachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;                 //Odnosi se na multisampling
    attachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;            //Operacija koju render pass attachment treba da obavi pri ucitavanju
    attachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;          //Operacija koju treba odraditi posle rendera
    attachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;       //Nije nam bitno kog je formata bila prosla slika, to ovo znaci.
    attachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;   //Slike koje treba da budu predstavljene u swapchainu

    reference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;//Layout slike u ovom subpassu
    reference.attachment = 0;                                   //Index attachmenta koji referenciramo ovim subpassom

    subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpass.pColorAttachments = &reference;                     //REFERENCIRAN JE IZ FRAGMENT SHADERA

    info.attachmentCount = 1;
    info.dependencyCount = 0;
    info.pAttachments = &attachment;
    info.pDependencies = nullptr;
    info.subpassCount = 1;
    info.pSubpasses = &subpass;
    info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;

    util->ErrorCheck(vkCreateRenderPass(this->renderer->getDevice(), &info, nullptr, &this->renderPass));
}
```

And finally, Framebuffer creation code:

```
void FrameBuffer::initFrameBuffer(
    uint32_t swapchainImageCount,
    std::vector<VkImageView> imageViews,
    VkRenderPass renderPass,
    VkExtent2D surfaceSize,
    std::vector<VkImageView> attachments
)
{
    frameBuffers.resize(swapchainImageCount);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < swapchainImageCount; ++i) {

        VkFramebufferCreateInfo frameBufferCreateInfo{};
        std::vector<VkImageView> allAttachments = { imageViews[i] };

        allAttachments.insert(allAttachments.begin(), attachments.begin(), attachments.end());

        frameBufferCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
        frameBufferCreateInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
        frameBufferCreateInfo.width = surfaceSize.width;
        frameBufferCreateInfo.height = surfaceSize.height;
        frameBufferCreateInfo.layers = 1;
        frameBufferCreateInfo.pAttachments = allAttachments.data();
        frameBufferCreateInfo.attachmentCount = allAttachments.size();

        util->ErrorCheck(vkCreateFramebuffer(renderer->getDevice(), &frameBufferCreateInfo, nullptr, &frameBuffers[i]));
    }
}
```

After running framebuffer creation code, I get these outputs:

Render Pass error on framebuffer creation:
[image: Render Pass error on FrameBuffer creation]

ImageView error on framebuffer creation:

[image: ImageView error on framebuffer creation:]

This error I get when I invoke `vkAcquireNextImageKHR()`:

[image: Swapchain Error]

This can't be a problem with a device or instance because I have enabled VK_surface_khr and VK_KHR_swapchain, and I have checked if my device and window support these extensions. Also, I have rebooted my PC and this errors still occur. I am using Vulkan SDK 1.1.85.0.

Also, there are no missing values in creation info structures except for pNext, which I think shouldn't even be used for now.

Comment: You are probably using the handles after `vkDestroy*`.

Comment: That's it. I was out of C++ world for good 2 years, so I forgot that C++ objects aren't like Java objects. Thanks!